# To write a macro for the clear all button in qlikview so that displays a certain selection

Tags: qlikview

I have a sheet that brings in data from a view (after some logic is applied to the view).

I set the state for the clear button. But when I press the clear all button the data shown is from the whole view instead of the data derived from the logic.

Please tell me a way through which even when I press clear all, only that particular set of data is displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clear All is always going to over-ride your Clear State settings, that is by design.

[image: Clear All]

The Clear State is relevant only to the standard Clear action.

[image: Clear]

You can lock the selections (right click Lock, turns the selections blue) then Clear All won't affect them.

[image: Lock]
[image: Locked Selection]

But obviously then if you use Unlock and Clear All it'll override the locked selections as well.

[image: Unlock and Clear All]

Comment: So, there is no way i can write a trigger for when the button clear all is clicked?

Also, when i lock it and a user right-clicks and presses on clear all selections then again the selections are overriden. 

Note that, there are no prior selections, the data is derived from logic that I have written in 'edit script'. So, when i clear all, the data of the whole view is brought back instead of the data that should be derived through the logic. 

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you want to limit the available data through the script why not use a stronger where clause? If the data doesn't need to be in the front end then remove it

Comment: I wasn't trying to to limit the data... I was bringing the limited data but when I pressed clear all it used to revert back to the data set derived from the view without the where clause. 

I created a bookmark and assigned it to a trigger whenever the clear all is clicked and that solved the problem. Thanks for helping.